# How to set up the Twitter gem in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'm a newbie developer a little mystified/overwhelmed by the documentation. I'm wondering how to implement the Twitter gem in a Rails 3.1 application.

1. I have the gem installed and know that I need to configure it, but where would I put this configuration information in a rails application? **and would it need to be altered in some way to get it synched with the rails app?**

   ```
   Twitter.configure do |config|
     config.consumer_key = ENV['CONSUMER_KEY']
     config.consumer_secret = ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET']
     config.oauth_token = ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN']
     config.oauth_token_secret = ENV['TOKEN_SECRET']
   end
   ```
2. do I have to require 'twitter' anywhere?
3. If I want visitors to my app to be update their status from my app, do I have to install Omniauth? or will this gem be sufficient?  i.e. if I require 'twitter' in the gem file and do bundle install, will bundler take care of everything I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question, are you using devise? If you are, this should be easier, as I'm building my own app with devise + omniauth + twitter. If you aren't, even though I'm a newbie rails developer myself, I'll try to steer you in the right path.

For starters, you should have a twitter account. You should then login [here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) and create your app. There, in the `Settings` tab you can choose the type of access or permissions you want to your user's twitter accounts. In my case, I'm using `Read only`, that is, I'm only using Twitter for authentication. Since you may want your users to update their statuses, you might want to take a look at the other 2 options: `Read and Write` and `Read, Write and Access direct messages`. You should also define a callback URL which is where Twitter returns after a successful authentication. Then you have several cosmetic options to pretty up your oauth dialog.
In the `Details` tab, you'll find your `Consumer key` and `Consumer secret` which you should never reveal and which you'll need in your Rails app.

In your app, you should be including these gems (and running `bundle install` afterwards):

```
#Gemfile
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

Then, in your initializers, you should create a file called `omniauth.rb` (you can call it whatever you like, but it's the standard) with the following:

```
#config/initializers/omniauth.rb
require 'omniauth-twitter'
config.omniauth :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET']
```

In my case, since I'm using devise, I included this in my `devise.rb` file, but it really doesn't matter where you include this as long as it's in a file in the `config/initializers` directory.

You should definitely take a look at the following sites:

[Omniauth's Github Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)

[The invaluable Railscasts by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)